# Golang : Variable argument

Tags: go

When I compile the following program

```
func myPrint(v ...interface{}) {
        fmt.Println("Hello", v...)
}
func main() {
    myPrint("new", "world")
}
```

I get a compilation error

```
too many arguments in call to fmt.Println
```

I thought v... is going to expand into 2nd, 3rd arguments and the fmt.Println would see three item variadic argument list. I thought it would be equivalent to

```
fmt.Println("Hello", "new", "world")
```

Why is it giving an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mis-using the variadic shorthand in your call to `fmt.Println()`.  What you're actually sending is 2 arguments: a single string, then the slice of type `interface{}` expanded.  The function call will not concatenate that into a single slice.

This design will compile and run with the results you're expecting:

```
func myPrint(v ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Print("Hello ")
    fmt.Println(v...)
}

func main() {
    myPrint("new", "world")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So it seems a slice of n elements expanded is not same as passing n arguments. What is the definition of expansion. Is there any reason why the compiler has to treat an argument followed by an expansion not same as one single expanded list

Comment: No, because the list must be collapsed into a slice by the underlying system, which will either 1) collect a set of single arguments or 2) pass a slice.  The easiest way to think about it is to match the ellipses if you're expanding a slice.

Comment: according to go specs, "We write ... after v in the nested call to Sprintln to tell the compiler to treat v as a list of arguments; otherwise it would just pass v as a single slice argument. "   

Based on the above statement the correct behavior should be treating it as a list of argument instead of a single slice argument.  I even tried the following and it doesn't work

   ` func myPrint(v ...interface{}) {
        fmt.Println(interface{}("Hello"), v...)
    }`

Comment: The issue isn't the compiler, but the parser.  The function call `fmt.Println("Hello", v...)` is parsed (using the comma) into two arguments, then sent to the compiler.  Without this, there would need to be a complicated set of type-checking and validation to decide if the preceding argument belongs in the list or not.  How would the compiler be able to match that call to the function if there was one function `fmt.Println(s string, v...interface{})` and another `fmt.Println(v...interface{})`?

Comment: This is the same reason two expanded slices can't be used for the same variadic list, such as `fmt.Println(v..., v...)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining this. So its the Golang's polymorphism coming in the way. I understand it now.

Comment: With parallel writes to std-out this could lead to another process/thread writing/printing something inbetween those print-commands. Please use the different answer provided by Rhythmic Fistman.

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It prepends Hello to the variadic arguments, then prints them all at once with `println`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func myPrint(v ...interface{}) {
    a := append([]interface{}{"Hello"}, v...)   // prepend "Hello" to variadics
    fmt.Println(a...)                           // println the whole lot
}
func main() {
    myPrint("new", "world")
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I also did the same to get by. But I would like to understand why the other doesn't work. Is this an expected behavior according to language specs or an anomaly of the compiler?